# Fermat's Prime test proof: Why does $\mathbb{Z}_n \setminus \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ consists of Fermat witnesses?

Tags: primality-test, carmichael-numbers

In a lecture I attended, we had a proof that if $n$ is a composite number, but not a Carmichael number, then it holds that the count of Fermat witnesses to the compositeness of $n$ in the set $\{1, \dots, n-1\}$ is at least $\frac{n}{2}$. As part of the proof (this was left as an exercise to the reader) it was was used that if we define $\mathbb{Z}_n^* = \{a \in \{1, \dots, n-1\} | gcd(a,n) =1 \}$ and then use that $\mathbb{Z_n} \setminus \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ consists of Fermat witnesses. Why is this the case (and does it only hold if $n$ is not a carmichael number)?

Comment: if $d=\gcd(a,n),$ then $d|n,$ so $n|a^{n-1}-1$ means $d|a^{n-1}-1,$ but $d|a,$ so $d|1$

Comment: did you mean $\mathbb Z\setminus\mathbb Z_n^*$?

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{Z}_n \setminus \mathbb{Z}_N^*$ indeed, sorry for that!

Comment: Are you using $N$ as a synonym for $n$?

Comment: Yes I did indeed - fixed that also (plus accepted your answer, thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $d=\gcd(a,n)$.  Then $d\mid n$, so $n \mid a^{n-1}-1$ means $d\mid a^{n-1}-1$,

but $d=\gcd(a,n)$ also means $d|a$, so $d|a^{n-1}$; all this means $d|1$, i.e., $d=1$.

Thus, if $\gcd(a,n)>1$ then $n\nmid a^{n-1}-1$.

I.e., if $a\not\in\mathbb Z_n^*$, then $a$ is a Fermat witness to the compositeness of $n$.

I think that's what you wanted to be shown.

This all holds whether or not $n$ is a Carmichael number.

If $n$ is a Carmichael number, then no element of $\mathbb Z_n^*$ is a witness to the compositeness of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is true regardless of whether $n$ is a Carmichael number.

$\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ is always well-defined.  It consists of all non-witnesses.  It is always a subgroup of the numbers relatively prime to $n$.  Therefore the size of that set divides the set of numbers that are relatively prime to $n$.

So far so good.

Where Carmichael numbers enter in is that $n$ is a Carmichael number, if and only if $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ contains **all** numbers that are relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_n^*$ is the group of numbers relatively prime to $n$; some of them may be witnesses; e.g., $3$ is a witness to the compositeness of $341$, but $3\in\mathbb Z_{341}^*$